# Amazon AWS 307 response and permanent redirect to HTTPS

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, redirect, amazon-ec2

I have a domain from GoDaddy, with AWS Route53 for managing DNS records. Route53 sends request to a load-balancer.

For webserver I have a load-balancer that routes requests to a single (for now) EC2 instance and the nginx in EC2 instance get the request and sends a response to the client.

The problem is that when I use `http://` to perform a request, AWS redirects requests to the `https://` version of the domain with `307 Internal Redirect` response. The response object has `Non-Authoritative-Reason: HSTS` header as well.

What's the problem and which component is redirected requests?

Comment: What listeners do you have configured on your ELB?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's neither component.

This isn't anything from AWS... it's the browser.  It's an *internal* redirect the browser is generating, related to HSTS... [HTTP Strict Transport Security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security).

If you aren't doing it now, then presumably, in the past, you've generated a `Strict-Transport-Security:` header in responses from this domain, and the browser has remembered this fact, preventing you from accessing the site insecurely, as it is intended to do.

Comment: I know nothing! Thank you.

Comment: You need to remove HSTS from your response header. In my case it was set from nginx add_header (ngx_http_headers_module).

Answer (score 11):

I know I'm lat eto the party but I wanted to post the actual full solution this this inspired from [this post](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/want-to-turn-off-http-strict-transport-security-hsts-header) on the Wordpress forums.

Just removing the HSTS header from the server will not solve it because the browser cached the HSTS response and will continue triggering https:// for that website regardless. In Chrome/Chromium you can delete the website from `about://net-internals/#hsts` but that's hardly a solution for your visitors as you have no idea how many already cached it as HSTS.

On the server side, you need to set `max-age=0` which will (as per the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6797)) ask the browser to stop considering that host as HSTS.

In Apache, do the following:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=0"
</IfModule>
```

and make sure you enabled the `headers` module (you can use `a2enmod headers` on Ubuntu/Debian/Mint).